# My Edit Page is not working

Tags: php, mysql

My edit page is not working. I keep getting 
Notice: Undefined variable. If I do put the form in closing tages the form just disappers when i click the update button

Notice: Undefined variable: post_title in C:\wamp\www\Persuasion\admin\edit_posts.php on line 57

0down voteaccept

I have to be honest I am very new to php. In fact this code is from a tutorial I am following http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oZ2KZRHASdQ. Unfortunatly the video freezes for the first 6 minutes, which is why I am asking for help

What I did is

```
<?php } } ?>
```

It seems to now work when I edit the post

But now I get this error

Notice: Undefined index: edit_form in C:\wamp\www\Persuasion\admin\edit_posts.php on line 96

Once again I would like to thank everyone who helping

```
 <html>
                <head>
                <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
                <link rel="stylesheet" href="admin_style.css" media="all"/>
                <title>Admin Panel</title>
                </head>

                <body>
                <div id="header">
                <a href="index.php">
                <h1>Welcome To Admin Panel</h1></div></a>

                </div>

                <div id id="sidebar">
                <h2><a href="#">Logout</a></h2>
                <h2><a href="view_posts.php">View Posts</a></h2>
                <h2><a href="insert_post.php">Insert New Posts</a></h2>
                <h2><a href="#">View Comments</a></h2>

                </div>
                <?php
                include("includes/connect.php");

                if (isset($_GET['edit'])) {

                    $edit_id = $_GET['edit'];

                    $edit_query = "select * from posts where post_id = '$edit_id'";

                    $run_edit = mysql_query($edit_query);

                    while ($edit_row = mysql_fetch_array($run_edit)) {

                        $post_id = $edit_row['post_id'];
                        $post_title = $edit_row['post_title'];
                        $post_author = $edit_row['post_author'];
                        $post_keywords = $edit_row['post_keywords'];
                        $post_image = $edit_row['post_image'];
                        $post_content = $edit_row['post_content'];

                        ?>

                <form method="post" action="edit_posts.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">

                              <table width="600" align="center" border="10" bgcolor="brown">

                                 <tr>
                                   <td align="center" bgcolor="yellow" colspan="6"><h1>Edit The Post Here</h1></td>
                                 </tr>

                                 <tr>
                                    <td align="right">Post Title:</td>
                                    <td><input type="text" name="title" size="35" value="<?php echo $post_title; ?>"></td>
                                 </tr>

                                  <tr>
                                    <td align="right">Post Author:</td>
                                    <td><input type="text" name="author" size="35" value="<?php echo $post_author; ?>"></td>
                                 </tr>

                                  <tr>
                                    <td align="right" >Post Keywords:</td>
                                    <td><input type="text" name="keywords" size="35" value="<?php echo $post_keywords; ?>"></td>
                                 </tr>

                                  <tr>
                                    <td align="right">Post Image:</td>
                                    <td>
                                    <input type="file" name="image">
                                    <img src = "../images/<?php echo $post_image; ?>" height="56.25" width="75"></td>
                                 </tr>

                                  <tr>
                                    <td align="right" >Post Content:</td>
                                    <td><textarea name="content" cols="30" rows="15"/><?php echo $post_content; ?></textarea></td>
                                 </tr>

                                  <tr>
                                    <td align="center" colspan="6"><input type="submit" name="update" value="Update Now"/></td>
                                 </tr>

                              </table>

                </form>

<?php }} ?>

                </body>
                </html>

                <?php

                if (isset($_POST['update'])){ 

                    $update_id = $_GET['edit_form']; 
                    $post_title1 = $_POST['title']; 
                          $post_date1 = date('m-d-y'); 
                          $post_author1 = $_POST['author'];
                          $post_keywords1 = $_POST['keywords'];
                          $post_content1 = $_POST['content'];
                          $post_image1 = $_FILES['image']['name'];
                          $image_tmp = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];

                    if ($post_title1=='' or $post_author1=='' or
                    $post_keywords1=='' or $post_content1=='' or
                    $post_image1=='') {

                    echo "<script>alert ('Any of the fields are empty')</script>";
                    exit(); 
                    }

                    else {

                    move_uploaded_file($image_tmp,"../images/$post_image1");

                    $update_query = "update posts set post_title='
                    $post_title1', post_date='$post_date1',post_author='$post_author1', post_image='$post_image1', post_keywords='$post_keywords1', post_content='$post_content1' where post_id='$update_id'";

                    if(mysql_query($update_query)) {

                    echo "<script>alert('Post has been updated')</script>"; 

                echo "<script>window.open('view_posts.php','_self')</script>";  
                    }
                }
                }


                ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

post_title is setted when you reach this:

```
isset($_GET['edit'])
```

Check how you acces there and your querys

**EDIT:**

```
 $edit_query = "select * from posts where post_id = '$edit_id'";
```

did you mean :

```
 $edit_query = "select * from posts where post_id = '".$edit_id."'";
```

Answer (score 0):

it seems that your database query is not returning any results. therefore $post_title variable is not set and you get undefined variable error. check if the query is working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

You should close your `if (isset($_GET['edit'])) {` after the form as the form cannot function without that information. I would also put the `POST` processing at the top so that you can show the same form with pre-filled values and an error message if the form could not be processed.

Apart from that you should also add some error handling in case no row-to-edit is found.

Lastly you should switch to PDO or mysqli ans prepared statements as the `mysql_*` functions are deprecated and you have a serious sql injection problem now.

Answer (score 0):

```
<form method="post" action="edit_posts.php?edit_forms=<?php echo $post_id; ?>" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

I think this will be helpful